# Hashrate steadily decreasing - GTX 1060

Tags: claymore, genoil

all.

I'm facing an issue with steadily decreasing average Hashrate on my rig.

I was using Genoil for a couple of days and my average, from Ethermine page, was hanging around 18MH/s. I'm doing some small OC, nothing fancy. I decided then to move to Claymore, because I was reading that I could get more than 18MH/s with my setup.

I started to play with my OC first on Genoil and couldn't notice any difference. Then I've moved to Claymore, ETH only mode. After that I notice a steady decline in the Hashrate average. I've tried to move back to Genoil, use the Cuda mining from Genoil, update Ethminer to 0.11, go back to Claymore, go back to my previous OC settings, but the trend continues. I was averaging 15.5MH/s at a point today.

Is there anything I'm missing?

My setup:
MSI GTX 1060 3GB ITX
Windows 10 Pro N

I will post later the rest of the details, since I don't remember by heart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all.

Sorry for the late response.

I've spent some time trying to figure out what was happening and, at the end, this is what I've found:

- My GPU has an optimal range of work. If I go over, it might look better on paper but the real results are worse.
- The hashrate displayed locally was misleading. I could see 18MH/s there, but the effective hashrate was almost 15MH/s when I've decided to try something.
- I've changed from Claymore to Genoil (my original miner) and, even though the local hashrate was lower, my effective hashrate went back to 18MH/s+, reaching 19MH/s at peaks.

In the end, the local hashrate displayed in the miner is just a basic idea of the performance for OC purposes. Sometimes the hashrate will go down a bit and the effective hashrate, at the pool, will go up. The only way to be sure is to let it run for 2-3 days and check the average at the pool monitor.

Maybe this was naive, noob's work, but what I was reading in different places was a little bit more consistent with the local hashrate.

Answer (score 0):

Your GTX 1060, only has 3 Gb of memory. The DAG size increases as more transactions are processed and more Ether is mined. Now, your 3Gb GPU will be affected by the DAG size and you will lose your h/s until That your GPU is no longer capable of mining.

With the current DAG size you need a GPU with 6 Gb of memory.